# I can't find "Knit" button in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I installed RStudio Desktop windows version to study a course on coursera, and i have to knit a certain RMD file. I installed all the packages including "knitr" but i still can't find a knit button in my interface.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is a 'Text File' button near the center of the window. Try clicking on that and selecting the 'R Markdown' option instead.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have an Rmd file open. Either change the extension of the file to Rmd an reopen it or create a new Rmd file from the “new” menu.

Answer (score 4):

I also have this problem despite having the correct file extension (.rmd) and the correct type of file at the bottom right of the source code window (RMarkdown).

I gave up searching when I found the keyboard shortcut: **Ctrl+Shift+K**

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu 16.04 and RStudio v1.1.419. I have two tabs open in the editor, both containing valid `.Rmd` files. Both are set to `RMarkdown` in the file type dropdown menu. One has a `Knit` button while the other has a `Preview` button. I don't know how RStudio decides what actions are valid.

Answer (score 4):

I'm taking the same course, so I'll comment in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

On the course page, you right-click the file, then click Save Link As, enter the file name as HomeworkWeek1.RMD, and change Save As Type to All Files. This is very important; if you do not save the file as a .RMD file the knitting will not work. Then in your file explorer, find where you saved the file. Right-click the file and click Open With -> R Studio. Then go to R Studio, and click Knit in the upper left corner. Then another window will automatically pop up with a cleaned-up version of the homework assignment.

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for this. I feel like they should have better instructions. Wasted a lot of time and nearly gave up. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the search field "Go to file/function" search for knit. after sometime knit option would be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since the question has posted. But none of the solutions above work for me unfortunately.

I have found the way works for me and would like to share in case anyone needs it.

In the R viewer -> click button 'Show in new window'. It will show the output table in a html web browser. Then you can copy and paste the table in the browser to Word without losing any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can always "knit" the file without using Rstudio interface just by

```
rmarkdown::render("file_name.rmd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your rmd file has the output mentioned as pdf. This part of the code needs to be included in the first chunk of your code, the part where you include title and details of the sort:

output: pdf_document
editor_options:
chunk_output_type: console

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).